# An adjactive for a "thing, that can't be lost"

Tags: word-request

We add '-able' to mark an ability and some prefix 'un-/non-/in-/..' to mark the negotiation. But I can't find in any dictionary I know and can reach the definition/translation of an adjactive(?) meaning a 'thing, that can't be lost/missed'. 'Lost' in meaning 'made unable to found (fast)'.

I tried variants 'unlosable', 'unmissable' and some semi-fantastic words, but couldn't find a definition/translation suitable for the purpose. The word is looked for to be a title/name/definition, so I can't split it more than 1 word. What word can you recommend me to use?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "unable to be lost" or "must not be lost".  For example my house keys are unlosable because I can't get into my house without them (I am able to lose them, but I must not).  My neon yellow jacket is unlosable because it is brightly coloured and impossible to hide it. . .   What is wrong with "unlosable"?

Comment: **Unlosable** is a perfectly fine word and [*No dictionary can ever tell you something is not a word!'*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/276039/106592)

Comment: @JamesK, I want to mean "unable to be lost". My doubt is based on the output of the translators (translate.google/yandex), that mark 'unlosable' with very different meaning (output something like "can't be closed"(?!)). I suspect 'unlosable' may have a widely-spread meaning different from what I wish to reach, so I ask the community for a possibly more acceptable variant. If the answer is 'no other variants there are in English', fine

Comment: Stop relying on computer-generated translation services. If they suck for translating stuff into your own language (and they do), then they suck for translating into English.

Comment: @FeliniusRex, stop forbidding me using non-perfect tools without suggesting working alternatives

Comment: It's not that the tools are not perfect, it's that they are seriously misinforming you. "Unlosable" has NOTHING to do with "can't be closed". It's not even close. I really wouldn't trust something that far off, but to each his or her own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Unlosable" is a meaningful word.

> Never struggle to find your keys with these *unlosable keys*! They have a built in GPS tracker that lets you locate them anywhere in the world.

It is true that "unlosable" is more usually used in the context of "a game that is impossible to lose",  or "something that *must* not be lost"